# Can the verb "kick start" be used in this sentence? Kick-start your skills in just 1 month

Tags: verb-usage

Can the verb "kick start" be used in this sentence?
Kick-start your skills in just 1 month

Context: Let's say I want to invite somebody to take a 1-month course and improve his/her skills. I want to include this sentence as motivation. Does it sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: Yes, for marketing.

Answer (score 3):

The verb "kick-start" is used that way, often enough to appear in dictionaries:
[American Heritage Dictionary "kick-start" (2)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=kick-start)

> 2. Informal To start or reinvigorate (an activity, system, or process): *kick-start the economy with a large construction project.*

This dictionary refers that definition of "kick-start" to the definition of "jump-start", which is used almost identically:
[Merriam-Webster "jump-start" (2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jump-start)
a : to start or restart (something) rapidly or forcefully *advertising can jump-start a political campaign*
b : to impart fresh or renewed energy to (something) : *energize a plan to jump-start the stagnant economy*

So, yes, it sounds natural, but it is informal.
The metaphor derives from the "kick starter" of a motorcycle. In the case of "jump start", it's from the use of another vehicle's battery to start a vehicle whose battery is dead.

Comment: Thank you so much!